# Which tool is more useful for generating code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-generation

i want to generate code for .net n-tier application.

or 3-tier application.

so which tool is more useful.

that will create all code.

Answer (score 2):

[Look into T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).  Also a better translator.

Comment: T4 templates are pretty powerful, and built into VisualStudio. They're quite usefully.

Comment: They are very usefully and customizability as well.  They can scans and created classes based on things like database schemas.  But who was template?

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for generating "all code" is called "brain".

Other than that, check out Codesmith.

Answer (score 0):

I do like Codesmith, and if you have the budget for it I recommend it.
There is also [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/) which is similar to Codesmith, and its free.

For the data layer you might check out [Subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo). (It uses T4)

There is also a product out there called [Iron Speed](http://www.ironspeed.com/)  I have not 
personally used this, but it is supposed to create a basic finished
application.